# Angular4 Exception: Can't bind to 'ngClass' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: angular, typescript

In my project I'm using lazy loading So, In my registration module I'm using `[ngClass]` directive to add invalid class when `formGroup` has some validation errors on my registration form. but my code throws an exception when trying to add `[ngClass]` directive on my form.

> Can't bind to 'ngClass' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

While investigating the error itself i came to several solutions, like adding the 'directive: [NgStyle]' to the component, but this does not solve the problem.

Here is my code:

**register.router.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RegisterComponent } from "app/modules/register/register.component";


const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '', pathMatch: 'full',
    component: RegisterComponent
}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
],
declarations: [RegisterComponent],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class RegisterRouter { }
```

**register.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RegisterRouter } from './register.router';  


@NgModule({
    imports: [
      CommonModule,
      RegisterRouter
],
    declarations: []
})
export class RegisterModule { }
```

**register.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

    @Component({
selector: 'app-register',
templateUrl: './register.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./register.component.scss']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

//#region Declarations
    UserForm: FormGroup;
    inValid: boolean = false;
//#endregion

constructor(
    private _fb: FormBuilder) { 
    this.UserForm =  _fb.group({
    "_firstname" : ['', Validators.required]
    });
}
}
```

**register.component.html**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{'ahinValid': inValid}" id="txtFirst_Name" aria-describedby="ariaFirstName" placeholder="Enter First Name"
          name="_firstname" [formControl]="UserForm.controls['_firstname']">
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Since `RegisterComponent` was declared in `RegisterRouter`(what's the name for module?) module then you have to import `CommonModule` there:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    CommonModule      <================== this line
  ],
  declarations: [
    RegisterComponent // this component wants to have access to built-in directives
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class RegisterRouter { }
```

Answer (score 31):

For anyone who's still having these issue even after importing `CommonModule`

I had a library that I just could not get to compile. I had several modules.. which were importing other smaller/components:

One of the components in one of my smaller modules had [ngClass] in it.. it would cause lib to not compile and throw `Can't bind to 'ngClass' since it isn't a known property of 'div'`

Apparently... i was exporting all my components for that modules... but not the module itself in the `public-api.ts` file (the module that did the import of CommonModule):

```
export * from './lib/af-layout/af-layout.module'; // <==== THAT WAS MISSING
export * from './lib/af-layout/components/af-layout-header/af-layout-header.component';
```

It took me a long time to find that.. as the error was directing me towards CommonModule not being imported.. not that an export was missing.

Comment: Where we should import from, because i try this but it says:
"Cannot find module './lib/af-layout/af-layout.module' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)"
Thanks

Answer (score 18):

Other than the **Common Module** being included in the **imports** of the parent module (e.g. app.module) , also ensure that the **component** that is raising the issue is actually included in the **declarations** of the parent module.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that I have wrongly imported module in my parent App module. I had to specify fully relative path for my library module and now it works fine :) Thanks toVS code  and its runtime syntax checker. It showed me error in import list.

Answer (score 7):

Lazy Loading Share module issue common solution:

> Both module must import `CommonModule`

In shared module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  ...
})
```

Module where you want to use component:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, ...],
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 7):

Import your component into the declations of @ngModuls of **anyName.module.ts** file.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I had this error because I uninstalled an external module and forgot to remove it from my imports array.

Apparently, if one import has an error it affects the whole module class.

So check for "red lines" in your module files if nothing else seems to work.

Answer (score 6):

You need to import commonModule

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case, when using Angular 17, I encountered an issue where I couldn't use [ngClass], *ngIf, *ngFor, Forms, but this was resolved by adding the following line:

[image]

Taking into account that the app.module.ts was replaced by the app.config.ts (in a certain way)

Link: https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services

Comment: or just import CommonModule

Answer (score 3):

Adding the Common module didn't work for me either.
Adding my Component to its module's "declarations" worked perfectly.

Reference - https://www.javaer101.com/en/article/42275629.html

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error.

Turns out it came after I moved a newly generated component from one folder to another. That move messed up the app.module.ts file.

I fixed the broken path, restarted ng serve, and voilà: Problem solved.

Hope this helps someone else, as I looked for solutions for hours and went through a complete npm re-install process, and more before stumbling on to this solution.

I blame my IDE for not informing me about the error in the app.module file, but ultimately this was caused by my own lazyness.

Answer (score 3):

In my case it didn't require the CommonModule import. I had just typed [ngclass] instead of [ngClass]. I guess its case sensitive and it needed the capital "C", instead of "c".

Answer (score 1):

If there anything wrongly imported or any imported thing missed in module.ts, this error may occur also. In my case, it happens.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Adding to this answer: having issues like "reference error", "unknown reference" or import errors can really throw the transpiler off and you'll get an avalanche of errors, among many "Can't bind to ngClass since it isn't a known property..".

Answer (score 1):

check **CommonModule**  imported and make sure **spelling** is correct i.e.
[ngClass]="{'your_class':condition}"

Comment: Haha, i just used [ngCLass] & didnt spot it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this problem happened after upgrading to Angular 14.

Almost *all* of the lines in my *app.module.ts* file were underlined with red lines.   And yes, I *did* already have this in my file:

```
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
```

Strangely, when I deleted a load of lines in the file, then hit CTRL+Z, most of the red lines went away, and I was just left with a red line on this line of code:

```
import { NgxDropzoneModule } from 'ngx-dropzone';
```

I removed this from my file, and everything built okay.

So, as others have said, it seems as though one tiny error in this *app.module.ts* file will give you hundreds of build errors elsewhere.  The trick is to find the one faulty line.

By the way, after seeing that my code built okay with this change, I did attempt to re-add the "faulty" library to my app again, and afterwards, it did all work okay.

```
npm install --save ngx-dropzone
```

Answer (score 0):

For people having this error on a **library project**.

In my case, this was caused by the **lack of a `ng-packagr` dev dependency**.

Adding this package as a dev dependency (`yarn add --dev ng-packagr`) fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when I deleted a component folder but didn't delete the import for it in the `app.module.ts`

It was just giving me this error in a total random place for some reason, if anyone else got it too, this may be a reason.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of `[ngClass]` you can use

```js
[class.my_class] = "step === 'step1'"
```

Comment: Hey, this is not the correct way.