# NgClass Error Angular (Can't bind to 'ngClass' since it isn't a known property of 'a')

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular10, angular4-forms

I'm new to angular, and I'm trying to dynamically add a bootstrap class to my html, based on the active tab, however, I'm getting an error. Can you help me?

My error: **Can't bind to 'ngClass' since it isn't a known property of 'a'**

My html component code:

```
<div class="p-5 bg-white rounded shadow mb-5">
  <!-- Rounded tabs -->
  <ul id="myTab" role="tablist"
    class="nav nav-tabs nav-pills flex-column flex-sm-row text-center bg-light border-0 rounded-nav">
    <li class="nav-item flex-sm-fill">
      <a id="home-tab" href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" (click)="viewTabName('In')" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true"
        [ngClass]="{active: activeTabName === 'In'}" 
        class="nav-link border-0 text-uppercase font-weight-bold">In</a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item flex-sm-fill">
      <a id="profile-tab" href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" (click)="viewTabName('Out')" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false"
      [ngClass]="{active: activeTabName === 'Out'}" 
        class="nav-link border-0 text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Out</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
```

My component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab',
  templateUrl: './app-tab.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-tab.component.scss']
})
export class AppTabComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor(){}

  activeTabName: string = '';
viewTabName(tab: string){
    this.activeTabName = tab;
    console.log(this.activeTabName);
  }
}
```

My app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({ 
declarations: [AppTabComponent],
 imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
]
})
```

Comment: try `[ngClass]="{ 'active' : activeTabName === 'Out'}"`

Comment: Maybe this can help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48288305/angular4-exception-cant-bind-to-ngclass-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of

Comment: Hi @Kshitij 
I tried this and several other ways to use ngClass and I get the same error: /

Comment: Hi @JeremyThille

I tried this, and added the CommonModule to my route module and my app.module, and I get the same error: /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please put class name in quotation marks

```
[ngClass]="{'active': activeTabName === 'In'}"
[ngClass]="{'active': activeTabName === 'Out'}"
```

Comment: Could you elaborate why the `{}` are necessary?

Comment: @RubenSzekér because it contains an expression